# Parsing a JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Maybe some one can help me to step in the right direction ?
Big Thanks for any Hints.

```
 var credentials = { steam: {}, rpc: {} };
 var rawCredentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("auth.json", { "encoding": "utf8" }));
 credentials.steam.accountName = rawCredentials.steam.accountName;
 credentials.steam.password = rawCredentials.steam.password;
 credentials.steam.shaSentryfile = new Buffer(rawCredentials.steam.shaSentryfile, "hex");
 credentials.rpc.username = rawCredentials.rpc.username;
 credentials.rpc.password = rawCredentials.rpc.password;
```

auth.json file

```
 {
 "credentials.steam.accountName": "XXX",
 "credentials.steam.password": "XXX",
 }
```

Cannot read property 'accountName' of undefined

Answer (score 6):

The key of your property is actually "credentials.steam.accountName". You can't use dot-notation to traverse to the objects "credentials" or "steam", as these aren't objects.
To access the values, use: `rawCredentials['credentials.steam.accountName']`.

Edit: If you want to use `rawCredentials.credentials.steam.accountName` your JSON would have to look like this:

```
rawCredentials = {
  credentials: {
    steam: {accountName: 'foo', ...}
  }
}
```

Comment: Well-designed JSON documents have keys that play nicely with JavaScript to avoid this sort of mess.

Answer (score 3):

Those are complete property names which contain dots, not actual nested objects, in your JSON file.

Also, you've forgotten the `.credentials` part. Instead, use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
credentials.steam.accountName = rawCredentials["credentials.steam.accountName"];
credentials.steam.password = rawCredentials["credentials.steam.password"];
```

(or refactor your JSON)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if that could be the problem, but you have a bad syntaxis in your auth.json:

```
{
  "credentials.steam.accountName": "XXX",
  "credentials.steam.password": "XXX"
}
```